# Is there a way to save tablerows into Firebase? Realtime or Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I made this mobile app that can add table rows after pressing a button. Each row contains an Edittext, four dropdown menus (spinners), and a button that deletes a row. Each row is like a duplicate after I press the button "add". Now, my only problem is how to save that specific content into firebase's real-time database or could firestore. Do you guys have recommendations of how to do this, any resources, or is this question is broad? I can specify some things you're confused.

I can save an edit text that holds the title for the document, and it successfully works, except the table rows because it holds multiple data types. I just heard that firebase can only hold primitive datatypes.

This is the code that is relevant to the problem, so I won't have to paste all 357 lines of code.

```
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar maintoolbar, editToolBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;


    private RelativeLayout layoutMain;
    private RelativeLayout layoutButtons;
    private RelativeLayout layoutContent;
    private boolean isOpen = false;


    private Button addnewRowButton, saveItButton;
    private EditText titleofDoc;
    private Context context = null;
    private ProgressBar pb;




    private DatabaseReference dr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        maintoolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(maintoolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Files");

        layoutMain = findViewById(R.id.mainLays);
        layoutButtons = findViewById(R.id.layoutButtons);
        layoutContent = findViewById(R.id.layoutContent);


        addnewRowButton = findViewById(R.id.AddRow);
        saveItButton = findViewById(R.id.SaveThis);
        titleofDoc = findViewById(R.id.TitleofDoc);
        editToolBar = findViewById(R.id.main_edit_toolbar);
        pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);


        saveItButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = titleofDoc.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    createNew(title);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Fill Empty Fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });


        addnewRowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewRow();
            }
        });

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewMenu();
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the method that makes the table rows.

```
    private void addNewRow() {
        final TableLayout tl = findViewById(R.id.tbllays);
        String[] teamRoles = {"Director", "Marketing", "Team", "All"};
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, teamRoles);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        //adds new row

        final TableRow tbr = new TableRow(context);

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tbr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        //add edittext to name the task
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        editText.setHint("Add Task");
        tbr.addView(editText, 0);

        //add spinner to assign teams
        Spinner toDo = new Spinner(context);
        toDo.setAdapter(adapter);
        tbr.addView(toDo, 1);

        //add spinner to assign teams
        Spinner InProgress = new Spinner(context);
        InProgress.setAdapter(adapter);
        tbr.addView(InProgress, 2);

        //add spinner to assign teams
        Spinner Test = new Spinner(context);
        Test.setAdapter(adapter);
        tbr.addView(Test, 3);

        //add spinner to assign teams
        Spinner Done = new Spinner(context);
        Done.setAdapter(adapter);
        tbr.addView(Done, 4);


        // Add a button in the second column
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText("X");
        tbr.addView(button, 5);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(159, 168, 218));

        // Get delete table row button.
        Button deleteRowButton = (Button) button;
        deleteRowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tbr.removeAllViews();
            }
        });


        tl.addView(tbr);

    }
```

This is the method that can only save the title instead of the content (the table rows in this case).

```
    private void createNew(String title) {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            final DatabaseReference newThingRef = dr.push();

            final Map thingMap = new HashMap();
            thingMap.put("title", title);
            thingMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            Thread mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    newThingRef.setValue(thingMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent MainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(MainIntent);
                            } else {
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            mainThread.start();


        } else {...}

    }
```

This is the xml file (the part where the editor is held)

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainToolBar"
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:visibility="gone">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                tools:context=".MainEditor">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinLay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="370dp">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/main_edit_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/TitleofDoc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:hint="@string/title"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType=""
                        android:maxHeight="1dp"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        tools:targetApi="o" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:alpha=".3"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fillViewport="true">

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tbllays"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TableRow
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/AddRow"
                                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="0"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"

                                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                                    android:text="@string/add_row"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/SaveThis"
                                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="1"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"

                                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                    android:text="@string/save" />
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:stretchColumns="*">


                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="0"

                                    android:text="@string/task" />

                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="1"

                                    android:text="@string/to_do" />

                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="2"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                                    android:text="@string/in_progress" />

                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="3"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                                    android:text="@string/testing" />

                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="4"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                                    android:text="@string/done" />

                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_column="5"
                                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                                    android:text="@string/delete" />


                            </TableRow>

                        </TableLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>


            </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Ignore the user part, that is only if the user is signed in.

[This is how it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGmoy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Listener at the end of each spinner and store in in the variable for example:

```
Spinner Done = new Spinner(context);
Done.setAdapter(adapter);
Done.setOnItemSelectedListner(this)
tbr.addView(Done, 4);
```

Then store this variable Done using DatabaseReference

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to save the rows, you want to save the *underlying content*.

Instead of thinking of the on-screen rows as the content itself, think of them as just displaying your underlying content. This underlying content can be backed up, modified, whatever you want, whilst the representation of it on screen can be completely reconstructed at any time.

To convert your code, I'd suggest the following series of steps:

1. Create something like a `Task` class, that has all the fields you want (e.g. `name`, `team`).
2. Store a list of `Task`s in your current Activity / Fragment class, e.g. `private List<Task> myTasks`.
3. Write a method `displayTasks` that removes all existing rows from your layout, then iterates through `myTasks` and draws them all to the screen.
4. Change `addNewRow` so that it adds a new `Task` to `myTasks`, then calls `displayTasks`.
5. You now have a list of Tasks, which can [be written directly into Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects), and be retrieved later.

I'm fully aware this answer isn't the simple "just do x" you're after, but it's the answer you actually need! All of the steps are very simple, and of course feel free to modify them for your use case.

Once you're comfortable with the concept of "what's on screen isn't my data, just a representation of it", you may want to look into [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). They're trickier, but with a lot of benefits (explained within the links).